# Обращение к переменной, постоянно меняющей часть своего названия, зная только только неизменную часть

Tags: javascript

Делаю небольшой автофильтр для одного сайта знакомств.

Чтобы добраться нужной информации нужно обратиться к переменной reactProps[image: введите сюда описание изображения], часть имени которой (после знака $) постоянно меняется (прикладываю фото).

Подскажите, есть какой-то способ обратиться к переменной по той части ее названия, которая не меняется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Решение

Вот так:

```js
const object = {
  ["_reactFiber$dsadadasda"]: 0,
  ["__reactProps$dsadadasda"]: 1,
  ["reactSomethingElse$dsadadasda"]: 2,
};

function detectReactProps(dictionary) {
  const regex = /^\w*reactProps\$\w+$/;
  for (const property in dictionary) {
    if (regex.test(property)) return property;
  }
}

const keyReactProps = detectReactProps(object);

console.log(object[keyReactProps]); // read
object[keyReactProps] = 5; // write
```

Comment: Опередили :) Еще можно просто property вернуть, что бы позже знать название переменной и как раз обращаться к ней напрямую позже

Comment: @SwaD, да! Ваш вариант лучше.

Comment: Друзья, спасибо, не знаю сколько бы времени без вас на это потратил :)

Comment: @Vakarine (✿◡‿◡)